# Как задать hover элементу с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я знаю, что можно добавить стили для элементов на странице подобным способом, который указан ниже. Но как задать так `hover` не знаю, а нужно именно через javascript, желательно без jquery.

```js
const container = document.getElementsByClassName('header_container') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>;
container[0].style.background = 'white';
```

Comment: в jquery есть метод hover()

Comment: В чистом javascript есть onmouseover и onmouseout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Повести на элемент обработчик [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) - чтобы выдавать цвет и [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) - чтобы "отбирать" цвет.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.elem'); // Берём элемент

btn.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){ // Вешаем на него обработчик mouseenter - при наведение мыши на элемент
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; // Выставляем цвет
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){ // И ещё обработчик mouseleave - при "уходе" курсора с элемента
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = ''; // Убираем выданный цвет
});
```

```css
.elem {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #09f;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">Наведи</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с ховером не обязательно навешивать события. Более подробно можно узнать в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) либо в этой [статье](https://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/js_theory/level2/2_4.php), разумеется в реальном проекте код будет чуточку сложнее приведенного ниже. Но лично я бы советовал пользоваться таким подходом когда нет реальной возможности задать стили заранее, например когда код генерируется в процессе его работы.

```js
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('h1:hover{color:red}', 0);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```